# Where am I going wrong with the count in Hql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

So I only want the count of the results not the results themselves therefore I am using count in hql. So, below is the query

```
(int)  Session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from TableName where Lhs=Rhs").UniqueResult();
```

But it is giving me the error `Specified cast is not valid.`.

So, can any body tell me how to cast the count to int.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: verify Lhs and Rhs column type

Comment: Can you debug and see what UniqueResult() is returning before the cast is done?

Comment: @jacerhea It is giving 0

Comment: As Nik said, it's working with Convert.ToInt32(). But can anybody tell me what is the problem with simple casting with (int).?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

Convert.ToInt32(Session.CreateQuery....);

Also verify if its really returning a count or null. This could be a possibility.

Thanks

Comment: Oh it's working, but any reason why it is not working with simple casting?

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a `long`, not an `int`. And you don't need the Convert either; you can use `.UniqueResult<long>()`.

Comment: @Diego: great comment on using the type converter method, forgot it was there.

Comment: I am glad that my first answer in stackoverflow has been accepted.However Diego is right. It could be a long and also he is right that you can use .UniqueResult<long>() instead of a Convert. Thanks for the pointer Diego.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
var temp = Session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from TableName where Lhs=Rhs").UniqueResult();

//check the type of the temp
temp.GetType();
```

I have a feeling that it is a Long and not an int.

Comment: in that case try casting it to Int64

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Casting because it is returning the single result (instance that matches the query) or null. 
What happens if you change it the int to be nullable?

Comment: do this instead:
var temp = Session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from TableName where Lhs=Rhs").UniqueResult();

//check the type of the temp
temp.GetType();

I have a feeling that it is a Long and not an int.